# Extract Function Declarations from Python-File using typescript

Tags: javascript, python, typescript, parsing

A Python-File should be parsed and each function should be extracted including signature, body and comments.

This should be done using Typescript.

Assume a source code in python:

```
def add(a, b):
    # Adds two numbers
    return a + b

def subtract(a, b):
    # Subtracts two numbers
    return a - b
```

I want to have each function signature including body and comments as string, so for example

```
const str1 = 

def add(a, b):
    # Adds two numbers
    return a + b
```

```
const str2 = 

def subtract(a, b):
    # Subtracts two numbers
    return a - b
```

in order to iterate through them.

I tried to use `'python-ast'` but have troubles to use the library

parsing of that file works and is implemented as follows:

`const codeAST = parse(inputFile);`

but I don't know how to continue up here...

Comment: The readme file has an example that finds and count function declarations. What specific problem are you having when you try to adapt that example to your needs?

Comment: Yes I saw this one. But I don't know how to modify it since there is also no real documentation on it